# How to add x% width to a div using jQuery

Tags: php

I have a kind of "loading bar" that is initially at 10% width.

```
<div id="loading_bar"></div>
```

Now I also have a form... that has different types of fields...

Each time when the form is submitted I need to add the width like, +10%, +20%

I wrote this code but it gives me pixels instead of percents...

```
$("#loading_bar").css("width", "+=20");
```

How can I write so it ADDS 20% instead of 20px..?

The value is not a constant one, it will change each time. So each time I need to increase the width according to the specified value. 
Can somebody please help... Thank you

Comment: Use the glue of the universe. Maths.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 20% of the containing element's width, and calculate what that is. The following function should work, depending upon your HTML structure:

```
var newWidth = $('#loading_bar').parent().width();
$("#loading_bar").css("width", "+="+(Math.round(newWidth * 0.2)));
```

Here, `0.2` represents 20%. You could easily explicitly set the percentage value using `20 / 100`.

Comment: its also adding px to the width

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#loading_bar").css("width", +=20+"%");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store that loaded value in some attribute like rel.

```
var loaded = $('#loading_bar').attr('rel');
var width = loaded + 20;
$("#loading_bar").css('width', width+'%');
$('#loading_bar').attr('rel',width);
```

Comment: `rel` is not a valid attribute for `<div>` elements. It'd be better to recommend the use of `data-` attributes.

Comment: add the attribute in #loading_bar element. ex <div data-width="20" id="loading_bar"> and and when you want to change the width you can get the width from the data-width attribute. ex $('#loading_bar').attr('data-width'). after you add the width you have to update the data-width attribute also

Comment: as BenM said dont use the rel attribute. please use data-width attribute. thanks you BenM

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
function increasePercentage($element, percentage) {

    $element.css("width", "+="+(Math.round($element.parent().width() * (percentage / 100))));

}

increasePercentage($("#loading_bar"), 20);
```